# program crashes because of object vector

Tags: c++, vector, crash, sfml

I'm making a program with a global vector filled with objects and putting it in a namespace here's the code:

*Character.h*:

```
#include <vector>
class Character
{
  //Constructor and variable declaration, etc.
}
class Player: public Character
{
  //Constructor and variable declaration, etc.
}
namespace chr
{
 extern std::vector<Character> characters;
 extern Player player_one;
}
```

*Character.cpp*:

```
namespace chr
{
 Player player_one("name");
 std::vector <Character> characters;
}
```

*main*:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> //I'm using the SFML libraries
#include "Personaje.h"

 int main()
 {
 Player player_two("name"); //just to test that single object work (they do)
 chr::personajes.push_back(chr::player_one); //HERE'S THE ISSUE
 
  //sample SFML code to check if the rest of the program works
 sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
 sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
 shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

 while (window.isOpen())
 {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
 }

return 0;
}
```

When I build this code (I'm using code::Blocks) it actually compiles without errors, but when I run it, as soon as the console comes up (the SFML window doesn't even pop up) it freezes and a Windows notification appears informing me that my program has stopped working.
I know it's the code on the **chr namespace** that is causing this because if I comment it out the program runs fine, but I don't know why this is.
If it's of any help, when the program crashes Windows opens the Visual Studio debugger, which produces this message:

> Exception thrown at 0x0044EFA2 in wtfhappened.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFC.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Thanks for your time

Comment: What debuggers are made for. If you think `//Constructor and variable declaration, etc.` for both `Character` and `Player` have nothing to do with this, I beg to differ until we *see that code*. My wild-ass guess is you're violating the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) in one, or both, of those classes. Or an [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) problem. Or perhaps both. And btw, `std::vector<Character> characters;` doesn't match your `std::vector <Personaje> personajes;`.

Comment: Code::Blocks is not a compiler but an IDE/Editor ...

Comment: What? Windows automatically opens the VS debugger? All by itself? Come again?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector <Character> characters;
```

This is a container for *Characters*. Not Players.

```
chr::personajes.push_back(chr::player_one);
```

This will take your Player, *and create a new Character from it to put into the vector*. All your information that Player has on top of Character will be lost and you are prone to something called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). I'll take a guess and say this is not what you want.

There are multiple ways to handle this. Start with not having a container of Characters, but a container of Character references (used in the plain English sense here, not C++ references). You may want to look into smart pointers (i.e. `std::shared_ptr<>`) for this to be as painless as possible.